# plm model "within" - Warning messages in R

Tags: r, warnings, plm

i have a problem running this plm model:

my data are (example):

```
    country=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
    year=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
    a=c(1,4,6,3,5,8,4,5,7)
    b=c(8,5,7,2,7,4,9,7,1)
    matrix=cbind(country, year, a, b)
    matrix=plm.data(matrix)
```

I run following regression:

```
    reg=plm(a~year+b, data=matrix, index=NULL, model="within")
    summary(reg)
```

and get following warning message:[1]

```
    Warning messages:
    1: In if (is.na(le)) { :
      the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
    2: In if (is.na(le)) " __no length(.)__ " else if (give.length) { :
      the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
    3: In if (le > 0) paste0("[1:", paste(le), "]") else "(0)" :
      the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

What is wrong?

Comment: That code throws an error in the line with `plm.data` with pkg:plm version 1.4-0.

Comment: @ user3237581: Have you found out more about this error? I would very much interested in this.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found an answer ([here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2014-February/366651.html))

This warning is given when a vector like this:

```
le<-c(4,2,6,5)
```

is used in a test like this:

```
if(is.na(le)) ...
```

R only looks at the first value in the vector for the test, but warns 
you that there were other values that were not tested. If the test was:

```
if(is.na(le[1]))
```

It doesn't matter if "le" has only one value or more than one and you 
don't get the warning. It usually doesn't mess anything up.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `str` checks the length of its object, and `plm` uses extended formulas from the `Formula` package. Now, `Formula:::length.Formula` returns a vector rather than a number, which causes the warning, as explained by simon_icl. While you may not call `str` yourself, perhaps your IDE, say RStudio, may use it to show the object structure of objects in the workspace.