# Code that only sometimes spits out a warning message in R

Tags: r, debugging, dataframe, warnings

I've got a very strange problem in R. I'm trying to run a `plm` with a certain panel `data.frame`. If i run the model, sometimes there's warning and sometimes there isn't. How is that possible? If i type `class(mydf)`, exactly the same thing, only sometimes a warning.
Does anyone know what this is about?

```
class(mydf)
[1] "data.frame"
Warning messages:
1: In if (is.na(le)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (is.na(le)) " __no length(.)__ " else if (give.length) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In if (le > 0) paste0("[1:", paste(le), "]") else "(0)" :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
class(mydf)
[1] "data.frame"
```

Comment: Is this in the standard R GUI? RStudio? The terminal? All objects or just this particular data.frame?

Comment: You need to make your problem reproducible, we are just as lost as you right now.

Comment: There is an answer to this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21364221/plm-model-within-warning-messages-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the cited page explains why this is happening at all. There is a bug somewhere. The code should be tracked down and the offending lines fixed:

```
if (is.na(le)) " __no length(.)__ " else if (give.length) {
```

.... should be changed to:

```
if ( all(is.na(le)) ) " __no length(.)__ " else if (give.length) {
```

I agree with Paul that you should make this reproducible.

Comment: It's reproducible with `data("Produc", package = "plm")`

Comment: When the data prints, take a look at line 419

Comment: Maybe it's a Windows-specific R bug or an old-R bug? When I execute: ` data("Produc", package = "plm");  class(Produc)` I get no warning.

Comment: The function was completely re-written last year.  I think I may have found the problem though. Or at least an idea where it occurs

Comment: So the poster (or you?) is using an out-of-date version?

Comment: No, the things bad.  I just installed `plm` today and I got the warnings.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `str` checks the length of its object and some objects, say the extended formulas from the `Formula` package does not have a single length. In particular, `Formula:::length.Formula` returns a vector rather than a number, which causes the warning. While you may not call `str` yourself, perhaps your IDE, say RStudio, may use it to show the object structure of objects in the workspace.